# Anatomically Correct Super-Intelligent Shade of Blue

Tags: science-based, creature-design, energy-beings

For the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798).

The super-intelligent shade of blue, or more properly, [Hooloovoo](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Hooloovoo), is exactly what it says on the tin. Whether the creature is intelligent in general or just compared to other, lesser shades of blue is left ambiguous.

It can:

- Refract in a prism (for special occasions).
- Turn purple when disgruntled about something.
- Meaningfully observe and interact with its surroundings, or it wouldn't be part of greater galactic society.

So we're looking at some kind of energy creature that behaves like light, and has to be blue for some reason. Though there isn't much literal anatomy to speak of, I would like to know if you could possibly build a creature out of material that can pass through glass, and have it be both intelligent and equipped with senses.

Comment: solution, its dark matter/energy

Comment: @Topcode Dark matter/energy doesn't interact with anything by their very definition; so how could it refract through a prism?

Comment: solution, it does interact (just not directly) so it could be emitting photons and only seem like its refracting through the prism.

Comment: Hyper dimensional beings that appear, in our dimension, to be white mice.... err... shade of blue.????

Comment: Excellent question! Ever since I read the book I have wondered how the Hyper-Intelligent Shade of the Color Blue worked.

Comment: @Marvin Now I'm confused; I was certain the shade was hyper intelligent, but the wiki said super so I corrected it to super, but now you too say hyper, hmmm

Comment: @KeizerHarm Don't correct it. I just pulled out my copy of *The Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, and it describes the Hooloovoo as "[a] *super*intelligent shade of the color blue" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @MarvintheParanoidAndroid, it almost certainly depends on edition and country along with Belgium which was US only.

Comment: @Separatrix watch your language! :) But in any event, yes; it is probably something that varies by region of publication.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a commercial third party intellectual property. WB.SE isn't for satisfying idle curiosity about other people's work.

Comment: @elemtilas I better delete it in that case.

Comment: @elemtilas Oh, looks like I can't. Very well, I'll vote to close my own question then - though I think off-topic is the better reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't any kind of real science, just so we're clear.  It's complete handwavium.

However ...

Let's assume your creature (and us) exist in some weird space with extra dimensions even the String theory people haven't tried out.  Your creature is made of stuff that mostly exists in an extended form in different dimensions from the ones we mostly exist in.  But ordinary light shares some overlapping dimensions.

Now ordinary light (photons) is a particle(and wave) that mediates the electromagnetic force, and as it happens solids we know and love (like glass) are solid because of good old electromagnetic forces.

So while your other mostly dimensional creature is not going to interact much with us, it is going to be affected by traveling through solids, like glass.  It's going to (maybe) be refracted.

It can't actually be stopped by glass or other solids because its like quantum particles that are entangled between dimensions (think long range bell's theorem) so that means the particles from that dimension cannot be stopped with particles from ours, just weakly scattered (weakly interact).

Well it's also energy in some form, so it's affected by gravity.  If it's got mass it could even be able to be affected just like we are.

Why does it appear blue?  Well it eats something (that's only in it's dimensional subset) and it radiates energy that's mostly in the blue spectrum.  It's probably a faint blue appearance, ghost-like, because we don't want to waste a lot of energy generating light.

So it can be seen by us, detect us, possible radiate different shades of blue (different wavelengths) in some ways to communicate with us.  It can be affected by gravity and walls and corridors (because it's affected by EM fields), but it has the option of walking through stuff if it doesn't want to politely observe our walls and doors (or just forgets to because in its dimension things are different).

And that, ladies  and gentlemen, is as much hand waving the laws of physics as I'm prepared to outline today. May Mighty Atheismo forgive me.

Comment: Honestly theoretical hyper-dimensions is exactly the kind of science-based I was looking for :)